# How to deal with such graphic design problem in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

As a part of flow chart design, I am facing an issue. On intersection of two lines, I need to design a bump where two lines are crossing each other. Is there any tool which solve such problems in Adobe Illustrator? Thank you in advance

[image: Illustrator_Graphic_Design]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bump is a separate object from the horizontal line. Your lines are set to terminate with a butt cap which is just a straight line. There are 2 ways to solve this:

1. Simply join the segments to make them one curve. Select the horisontal lines and the bump, then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> to join them.
2. Use a Round cap on all 3 of your lines. This way the curves will overlap. This is easier if you have lots of these. Just apply a round cap an all lines and be done with it.

Comment: thanks a lot. ctrl + j solved my problem. by the way, How could you write `ctrl` + `j` graphically over here? I want to learn that as well.

Comment: @python `<kbd>ctrl</kbd>`, you should consider accepting answers then you can start acquiring score and you could look up what i wrote myself by just editing the post.

Comment: thank you, I got **+2** after accepting your answer. Feeling Good!

Comment: @python the problem is that you had a trackback of not accepting it make people reluctant to answer

Comment: @python see now you have enough score to vote. Review your questions so far